# How to get jquery datepicker in telugu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I got the datepicker in different languages. i referred https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n but i did not find the telugu related datepicker.

Comment: You have to use like this language: 'ru'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an approach:

Your desire file is `"datepicker-in-TEL.js"`

```js
  $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "in-TEL" ] );
  });
```

```css
body {
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", "Helvetica", "Arial",  "Verdana", "sans-serif";
 font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//uttamkumarroy.com/datepicker-in-TEL.js"></script>

<p>Telugu Date Picker: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Welcome Veeresh brother. If you think my post helped you then reward it by upvote or accept